# Missing SPARK_HOME when using SparkLauncher on AWS EMR cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, emr, amazon-emr

I am using EMR 5.0 with Spark 2.0.0. 
I am trying to run child spark application from Scala spark application using org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkLauncher

I need to set SPARK_HOME using setSparkHome:

```
 var handle = new SparkLauncher()
    .setAppResource("s3://my-bucket/python_code.py")
    .setAppName("PythonAPP")
    .setMaster("spark://" + sparkSession.conf.get("spark.driver.host") +":"+ sparkSession.conf.get("spark.driver.port"))
    .setVerbose(true)
    .setConf(SparkLauncher.EXECUTOR_CORES, "1")
    .setSparkHome("/srv/spark") // not working
    .setDeployMode("client")
    .startApplication(
      new SparkAppHandle.Listener() {

        override def infoChanged(hndl: SparkAppHandle): Unit = {
          System.out.println(hndl.getState() + " new  state !")
        }

        override def stateChanged(hndl: SparkAppHandle): Unit = {
          System.out.println(hndl.getState() + "    new  state !")
        }
      })
```

Where can I find the appropriate path to my Spark Home ? 
The cluster is built from 1 Master, 1 Core and 1 Task servers.

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly, this would run on the EMR cluster, but wouldn't use EMR steps, right?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As of emr-4.0.0, all applications on EMR are in /usr/lib. Spark is in /usr/lib/spark.

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same error: 

`16/09/18 09:07:02 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/lib/spark/bin/spark-submit": error=2, No such file or directory
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/lib/spark/bin/spark-submit": error=2, No such file or directory
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
 at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkLauncher.startApplication(SparkLauncher.java:428)`

Comment: Are you not running this on the master instance? If Spark is installed, /usr/lib/spark definitely exists on the master, but it does not exist on the other modes.

Comment: Btw, I also noticed that you set the Spark master to spark://..., but that is not correct for Spark on EMR, since it runs on YARN. The correct Spark master is just "yarn".

Comment: so if I am setting master=yarn, how can I run it on master ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure exactly what you are asking. You are running on a cluster that has Spark installed, but you claim that you still get an error saying that /usr/lib/spark/bin/spark-submit does not exist, but that's not true if you are running the command on the master instance. If that file doesn't exist, perhaps you are somehow running on the wrong instance? I'm not sure how that would be the case, but you haven't really provided enough information about how you are running this.

Answer (score 2):

I find out that Spark on AWS EMR (tested with version emr-5.23.0 & emr-5.22.0) doesn't install Spark on EMR CORE Nodes. Just check the EMR nodes installation on /usr/lib/spark, it's not really a SPARK_HOME like the one installed on the EMR MASTER node.

Installing Spark on EMR CORE Nodes solved my issue.

Comment: I am having the same issue right now, but is it really a solution to install Spark on EMR Core nodes, though? It sounds like a complete hack. I am not sure why the Core nodes don't have the same Spark setup as the Master.

Comment: Well, I don't know why but it makes things working at least. You'd better asked someone on AWS EMR support. I haven't tested on recent version of EMR however, maybe it's fixed now.